# List first letter of categories - issue upon spcecial characters (danish letters)

Tags: list, characters

I have a alphabetic list of custom taxonomies (Topics), all taxonomies are grouped by a index letter - A, B, C etc. The list uses the first letter of "Topic", to show as a index letter for each alphabetic group.

The alphabetic groups works perfect, but when it shall show the Danish letters Æ, Ø and Å, I get faulty letters like � instead of Å. I the database is set to utf8_danish_ci and so is wp-config.php

I really cannot figure out how to control $letter to show Æ Ø Å. Any help is much apreciated :)

[enter link description here](http://athenasdanmark.wpengine.com/emner/)

Code used:

```
<?php $list = ''; 
$tags = get_terms( 'topic' ); 
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
$first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );
$groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;}
if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
$list .= "\n\t" . '<div id="index-letter"><h2>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) .'</h2></div>';
$list .= "\n\t" . '<ul>';
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
$lower = strtolower($tag->name);
$name = str_replace(' ', ' ', $tag->name);
$naam = str_replace(' ', '-', $lower);
$list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a href="/topic/'.$naam.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
}}}}else $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>Beklager, men ingen emner blev fundet</p>';print $list;
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Check your blog charset in your admin settings and your theme or plugin files. It's probably some `latin-0-9`/ISO-* subset instead of UTF-8.

Comment: I did that in the first place, and the solved alphabetic order, but not issue about special characters. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Multibyte String functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php), in this case [`mb_strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php).

This is a general rule: in WordPress, output is usually encoded in UTF-8. Avoid single-byte functions like `strlen()`, `substr()` and others when there is a better `mb_*` function.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks correct. I must admit that I have pasted the code of some other post at Stackexchange, so I have not build it myself.

When I replace:
$first_letter = strtoupper( $tag->name[0] );

with:
$first_letter = mb_strtoupper( $tag->name[0] ); 
the list works, but it does not output any of the special letters. All "normal" letters is listed ok.

Comment: Solution: $first_letter = mb_strtoupper( mb_substr($tag->name,0,1) );